# Formally changing the #4 migration target

Tags: discussion, status-completed, migration

Whereas, the migration statistics as discovered [in this meta post](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/2582/the-state-of-the-4-migration-target) show a demonstrated and ongoing trend of mod-only migrations to dba.stackexchange.com, and

Whereas, Webmasters has not resided in the top-4 migration destinations for many months, and

Whereas, the changing nature of released StackExchange sites has fundamentally altered the nature of does-not-belong-here questions,

**Therefore be it resolved:**
That the 4th migration path for ServerFault be changed from Webmasters to DBA in order to better enable the ServerFault close-voting population to migrate these questions without Moderator action.

---

Voting will remain open until 1800UTC Jan 14, 2012.

Debate is now open.

Comment: Note: Adding U&L to spot #5 is a separate debate, and not topical here.

Comment: Agree. I'm probably chief flagger for DBA.SE on SF and SO

Comment: Voting is closed. Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Deferred?! Until when?

Comment: @ChrisS Until I can get an actual answer out of a dev.

Comment: @sysadmin1138 Looks to be done now; we've got U&L as well as DBA, and Webmasters is gone.

Comment: Probably too late to weigh in now but the ideal would be for the 4 options to dynamically change based on the tags on the question.  If it's tagged [ubuntu], make AskUbuntu an option.  If it's tagged [mysql], make DBA.SE an option, if it's tagged [security], make Security.SE an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Migration targets have been change, some statistics of interest from a [related Meta.SO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118685/should-some-communities-have-more-than-4-migration-targets).

> In the last 90 days (data gathered on January 15th 2012), Server Fault
>   has had 597 question migrated away from it:
>
> - Super User†: 332, 12% rejected
> - Stack Overflow†: 74, 10% rejected
> - Unix & Linux: 47, 14% rejected
> - DBA: 35, 8% rejected
> - Apple: 32, 0% rejected
> - Web Masters†: 27, 7% rejected
> - Ubuntu: 20, 5% rejected
> - Security: 18, 0% rejected
> - SharePoint: 7, -- not enough data
> - Programmers: 2, -- not enough data
> - WordPress, Web Apps, Project Management, Electronics: 1 each, -- not enough data
>
> <sub>†Existing migration targets at time of writing.</sub>
>
> Tossing out the rejections, this would mean that approximately **154
>   legitimate migrations** were not covered by our migration targets
>   (compared to  384 that were).
>
> Note, there's about a 10% chance the migration is rejected (closed on
>   the destination site); this is important.

Comment: What do you consider "rejected"? Do you consider "Closed as duplicate" as a rejection, for example?

Answer (score 17):

As a DBA mod I am receptive to this with no hesitation, I only ask that people who do choose to migrate consider our FAQ.

When moderator-only migrations occur, it is often discussed with the mods beforehand, specifically because there may be some hesitation between both parties, especially so in our case, as early on we did not appropriately define our FAQ.

Having resolved that issue (by appropriately defining our FAQ) we think that it is able to stand up to the test of "does this Question belong on dba.se" and invite any serious inquiry to make sure that we have adequately defined the FAQ.

Thank you all for your consideration of that FAQ, and for helping us to refine it in any way that it is unclear, or needs examples.

Since it was mentioned I should link to the FAQ in question, here you go: https://dba.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: I like the DBA.SE FAQ -- It's very obvious what kind of questions you're looking for.

Comment: Even better, you knew what I meant, when I accidentally a word there. Fixed.

Comment: You do realise of course that we can't get people to read our FAQ, let alone yours. :(

Comment: I know, but the ones who _care_ to are the same, here and there, and are also the ones reading this page. I'm one of the ones who _do_ and I generally pull the FAQs if I haven't read it in a week or so when deciding to migrate something.

Comment: @jcolebrand: You get a million points just of taking part in this discussion.

Comment: @pauska being as how I'm the guy on the receiving end, I should be part of this discussion ;-)