# Need some clarification

Tags: discussion

I flagged the following item as being possibly not appropriate to ServerFault suggesting another possible group.  I got the following reply for the question https://serverfault.com/questions/358965/why-is-my-ubuntu-system-not-using-the-correct-kernel

"Why is my Ubuntu system not using the correct kernel? [migrated]
asked 2 days ago by Brooks Moses
Hmmm....sounds like this thing belongs in the UNIX group...what do you think? – 2 days ago "

**declined - U&L is now a close target for us. You can cast Close -> Off Topic-> Belongs on unix.stackexchange.com yourself.**

However, it was eventually migrated to the Ubuntu group.  Thus, this decline seems odd to me based on the final result which was indeed a migration indicating an improper group.  I'll admit that I didn't have the appropriate group but I asked the question and suggested a course of action.

Why the inconsistency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't read the question to determine if it should stay or not - I just read your flag comment. I then declined your flag because you could have cast your own [vote to close](https://serverfault.com/privileges/close-questions) the question but chose to flag for moderator attention instead.

Subsequently someone else flagged for migration to askubuntu (which is not a close target for SF) so I paid more attention to the question and went and asked in [their chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3356269#3356269) if they would like it and migrated it away. I suspect it would have got an answer here too though.

The preferred method for moderation is via the community and moderator intervention should only be requested when you or the community can't do it yourself.

Comment: I can't say a close is appropriate whereas a migrate might be.

Comment: Migration is a form of close. Click on the close link under a question and see.

Comment: @mdpc Specifically Migration is an option when you close something as Off-Topic (it gives you the chance to send it to some of the places we usually migrate things to).  That list is by no means exhaustive ([or static](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/2589/formally-changing-the-4-migration-target)) though, so if you know of a better home for something and it's not on the short list definitely flag it to let us know.

Comment: Do moderators check on 'close' information like flagging a post?

Comment: I do, I can't speak for the rest of the mods though.

Comment: I'm pretty sure most of us **do** look at the close votes and whatnot in situations like this.

Answer (score 3):

There were two flags on that question, yours was the first.

It was declined since your stated migration target, U&L, is actually a close option now and you really should be using close-votes for that not flags. If you are unsure of a migration target, just that it's off topic in some way, a straight close-vote is appropriate.

A second flag came in stating much the same thing, but asking for a migrate to Ask Ubuntu. The moderator who handled that flag agreed, and it was migrated.

Comment: I only try to make a suggestion, I did feel that it belonged elsewhere.  So you are saying that instead of flagging this to people that might be able to migrate it appropriately (I don't that that priv) with a suggestion (not necessarily right) that a close is more preferred?

Comment: what you are also implying by your statement, is that perhaps one should be less specific in the verbage on a moderator flag.  I only try to help the moderator who I suspect has more global knowledge than I.

Comment: @mdpc If you really are unsure where it should go other than 'not here', close-vote for straight OT. Then follow up with a flag for where you think it might belong (so long as that list is not one of the 5 migration targets we have). If it gets hammered, your name will appear on the close-credits list like it should.